# make a file browser in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, file-browser

I really want to make a simple file browser in Xcode kind of like Finder itself, but it just displays one folder as a grid view. Can anyone direct me to a guide?

Comment: do you mean a table (with rows and icons on the side, like list view in Finder) or a grid of icons (like the icon view in Finder)? For the former, use NSTableView or NSOutlineView. For the latter, use IKImageBrowserView.

Comment: I wanted the icon grid, to display files in a folder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend looking at Apple's code sample for [SourceView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html).

It's probably a good place to start and should give you enough of an idea of where to begin.